# paperclip undefined method 'photo_of_recipe' for nil:Nilclass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, undefined-symbol

I'm trying to use paperclip and it isn't recognizing the symbol for the attachment - :photo_of_recipe. Instead, when I try to load the recipe with the attachment, it says:

```
undefined method `photo_of_recipe' for nil:NilClass
```

I ran:

```
rails g paperclip recipes photo_of_recipe
```

Here is the attachment code from the recipes model:

```
has_attached_file :photo_of_recipe, :styles => { large: "600x600",   
medium: "300x300", thumb: "100x100#" } 
validates_attachment_content_type :photo_of_recipe, :content_type => 
/\Aimage\/.*\Z/
```

I'm guessing the error is due to the fact that :photo_of_recipe isn't technically an attribute of the Recipe object. Here are the parameters for the Recipe object:

```
2.0.0-p598 :002 > Recipe
=> Recipe(id: integer, title: string, body: text, published_at:   
datetime, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, user_id: 
integer, photo_of_recipe_file_name: string, 
photo_of_recipe_content_type: string, photo_of_recipe_file_size: 
integer, photo_of_recipe_updated_at: datetime)
```

Here is the message from my rails console when I try to load the recipe:

```
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-02-24 17:50:16 -0500
Processing by RecipesController#index as HTML
Recipe Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "recipes".* FROM "recipes"
User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 
? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
Rendered recipes/_recipe.html.erb (2.4ms)
Rendered recipes/index.html.erb within layouts/application (3.9ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 6ms

 ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `photo_of_recipe' for  
 nil:NilClass):
 8:       </span>
 9:       <% end %>
10:   </h3>
11:   <% if @recipe.photo_of_recipe %>
12:     <%= image_tag @recipe.photo_of_recipe.url %>
13:     <%= image_tag @recipe.photo_of_recipe.url(:medium) %>
14:     <%= image_tag @recipe.photo_of_recipe.url(:thumb) %>
```

Oh, and `:photo_of_recipe` is permitted in my recipe controller in recipe_params, so that's not the issue.

Is this maybe because I haven't created a Photo_of_recipe model? I don't want to do that, unless that is common practice for attachments. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you show us your ``Recipe`` call that's giving that error? It looks your paperclip is OK, the error is that you're not having a ``Recipe`` there in your call, but ``nil``.

Comment: I added the message from my rails console when I try to load the recipes page. Does that help you, or were you looking for something else?

Comment: My guess : change  @recipe for recipe

Comment: You can help us showing the partial ``recipes/_recipe.html.erb`` and the where is it called here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that you are calling your `recipes/_recipe.html.erb` partial somehow like this:

```
render @recipes
```

what will store each `Recipe` in a local variable `recipe` available within your partial.

In you partial, you are calling your `Recipe` as it were a class instance variable. Just change any call to `@recipe` to `recipe` in your partial and you should be OK.

Comment: Thank you so much, that fixed it.

Just so I understand: partials don't need to call model objects as a class instance variable since they have already been instantiated when the partial was rendered?

Comment: You just dont have that (singular) variable defined, ie its nil. Have a look at the guides, its clear there. Alzó, dont forget to accept and upvote if it was helpful.